# Android emulator: how to have primary and secondary external storage folders on avd (/mnt/sdcard and /mnt/external_sd)

Tags: android, storage, android-virtual-device, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to have /mnt/sdcard and /mnt/external_sd folders on emulated device with Android 4.4.

I am testing Android 4.4 new access rules for external storage so I need that the avd has primary external storage and secondary external storage. They have to be recognized by the system as an array of external storage locations: main location has to be /mnt/sdcard which has different access rules from secodary one in Android 4.4.

I would like to put some options in the run configurations target "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field to have also a secondary external storage (/mnt/sdcard is already present, I just want to add the secondary external storage).
Other methods are welcome too.

How to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, the emulator does not support this at the present time. Rather, you would test this using Android 4.4+ hardware.

Comment: @CommonsWare Any news about this? I would really like to try out the "DocumentFile" API, and try it out, but I can't find any way to check it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Um, well, AFAIK the emulator still does not support emulating removable media or arbitrary other partitions, except perhaps via some custom emulator "firmware" build. `DocumentFile` does not depend upon removable media, though -- it just needs a `DocumentsProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. Do you know of any kind of such an emulator "firmware" ? Also, about DocumentFile, I mean I want to check it in an environment that's as natural as a real device with a real SD-card, because as I've understood, Lollipop provides a way to reach those files using the user's approval.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "Do you know of any kind of such an emulator "firmware" ?" -- I have never gone looking for one. You might see if Genymotion supports this. But I'd test it on hardware.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. Do you know perhaps of a nice sample of how to use the DocumentFile, that fully supports (real)SD-cards ?

Comment: I haven't played with `DocumentFile` yet. The Storage Access Framework, though, isn't dependent upon `DocumentFile`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't understand. How do you access the SD-card ? Is it ok to use normal "File" class? How do you gain access to it? It's just that I don't have a device that has an official Android Lollipop rom together with an SD-card. It's quite a rare thing to see these days...

Comment: "Is it ok to use normal "File" class?" -- that depends. That's possible on Android 4.3 and below, but the mount points vary and are undocumented. On Android 4.4+, you're welcome to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin (note the plural "dirs", compared to the original `getExternalFilesDir()`) to get you a private spot on removable media. Beyond that, you're using `MediaStore` or the Storage Access Framework, depending upon what "access" you need. With regards to the SD card, use a USB OTG thumb drive instead. And if you have additional concerns, ask a fresh SO question.